# Recursive binary tree class of Fibonacci sequence

Tags: c++, data-structures, recursion, binary-tree, fibonacci

As part of a personal project, not homework - just for my own interest and getting started in C++ I'm trying to create a binary tree of Fibonacci values; **I know I'm making a number of fundemental errors here**, but would appreciate if someone could help me out, my code is below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;

class FibTree {

    class Node {
    public:
        Node const* left;
        Node const* right;
        int value;
        Node (int, Node*, Node*);
    };

    Node const* root;

public:
    FibTree (int);
    int getValue(){
        return this->root->value;
    };

private:
    static Node* buildTree(int n ) {
        if (n < 2) {
            return new Node( n, NULL, NULL );
        } else {
            Node* left = buildTree( n - 1 );
            Node* right = buildTree( n - 2 );
            return new Node( left->value + right->value , left, right );
        }
    }
};
FibTree::FibTree(int n) {
    this->root = buildTree(n);
};

FibTree::Node::Node(int value, Node* left, Node* right){
    this->value = value;
    this->left = left;
    this->right = right;
};

int main () {
    FibTree f(6);
    cout << f.getValue();
    return 0;
}
```

Could anyone let me know what I'm doing fundamentally wrong here, importantly tell me why I'm getting the errors **'Cannot convert 'FibTree' to 'FibTree*' in assignment**; and how I should better approach?

Thanks in Advance,
Alex

Comment: The whole implementation is wrong; you need to rewrite the code from scratch.

Comment: `this->left = new FibTree(n - 1, this);` is how you fix the error you get (in return for some memory leaks, but they don't do harm). But I agree with you: you're making a bunch of fundamental errors. But I'll leave that to someone who wishes to construct a complete answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message says, you're trying to assign a concrete
type `FibTree` to a pointer.  In many cases, the error is that
you are using pointers, but in this case, identity is important.
You want one, and only one instance of `FibTree` for each value.

Since your goal is apparently to learn good practices, I will
start out by pointing out that the abstraction you seem to be
implementing in `FibTree` is *not* that of a tree, but of a node
in a tree.  Personally, I would have started with something
like:

```
class FibTree
{
    class Node
    {
        Node const* left;
        Node const* right;
        int value;
    };
    Node const* root;
public:
    //  ...
};
```

After that, it's more a question of personal preferences how you
want to build up the tree; the important point is that each node
must be dynamically allocated (`new Node(...)`, and not just
`Node(...)`), and that the `left` and `right` pointers must be
elements that are already in the tree.

Beyond that, I'm not sure how much you want me to tell you,
Working out the rest could be an interesting learning
experience, but if you want more hits, feel free to ask, and
I'll edit this answer to provide them.  One thing I would say:
I'd add a constructor to `Node`.  Something along the lines of
`Node::Node( int value, Node* left, Node* right )`.  Strictly
speaking, you don't need it, and it won't change the algorithm
in anyway, but it will make writing the algorithm out much more
succinct.  Also, I'd use a recursive function to build the
structure, called from the constructor.  And finally, I'd add a
destructor at the tree level, which walks the tree recursively
deleting all of the nodes.

But I repeat: the most important single point to grasp is that a
node is not the tree.

Comment: Many thanks for your great advice; I'll explore your points and get back to you with any questions if thats okay. Alex

Comment: Hi James, I've added in the nested Node class, however having problems declaring the Node class constructor:
`class FibTree {

 class Node {
 public:
  Node const* left;
  Node const* right;
  int value;
  Node (int, Node*, Node*);
 };
 Node::Node (int value, Node* left, Node* right);
 
public:
...`

Errors with _italic_Cannot declare member function 'FibTree::Node::Node' within 'FibTree'_italic_ do you you why this would be the case? Thanks Alex

Comment: If you're defining the constructor for `FibTree::Node` out of the class, the format would be `FibTree::Node::Node(...)`.  Also: you can define the implementation of the constructor directly in the class definition of `Node`, or you can define it in global scope, but you cannot define it in the scope of the enclosing class.  (I usually don't like defining functions directly in the class definition, but for almost trivial constructors of nested classes, I'll often make an exception.)

Comment: Thanks James; thinking about this (and with some trial and error), whilst waiting for your reply, I worked this out - so this is something else I've learned. You advise calling a recursive function to build the tree from the constructor - would this be from the tree constructor, as opposed to the node constructor?

Comment: Hi James, I've updated the code above; I need to understand more clearly the relationship between the FibTree and Node classes; as you can see I've created a buildTree method called from the FibTree constructor - is this correct; I know the method isn't correct in that it errors with _italic_Void value not ignored as it ought to be_italic_, on the code `root->left = buildTree(n - 1, new Node(n - 1));root->right = buildTree(n - 2, new Node(n - 2));` but you can see what I trying to do recursively. How and where should I be building the tree structure? Thanks Alex

Comment: @Alex2134 For starters, I'd make `buildTree` private.  And I'd probably have it return a `Node*`.  I've only given the code a quick look, but my impression is that you're building in the wrong direction.  Something along the lines of `Node* buildTree( n ) { return n < 2 ? new Node( n, NULL, NULL ) : new Node( n, buildTree( n - 1 ), buildTree( n - 2 ); }`.  In the constructor, you can initialize `root` directly from `buildTree`, in the initialization list (and `buildTree` can be `static`, since it doesn't need a `this` pointer).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion for the buildTree function, I think its slightly incorrect in that `new Node( n, buildTree( n - 1 ), buildTree( n - 2 ));` should be something like `new Node( currentNode.left.value + currentNode.right.value, buildTree( n - 1 ), buildTree( n - 2 ));` Not sure how to implement this with the current `buildTree` function.

Comment: Hi @JamesKanze excellent, I had a further think about the `buildTree` function and have amended my code above. It seems to work nicely. I never seem to be able to approach a recursive problem the right way, it's a case of practice I think.

Comment: Hi @JamesKanze could you clarify for me... Does `Node const* root` declare the `root` variable as a Node Constant pointer? Also I assume on the `buildTree` function declaration `Node*` means that the function returns a pointer of data type _Node_ is that correct? One last question... why are we declaring the _Node_ variables as Constants? Thanks again, Alex

Comment: It's possible that there were errors in my suggestions; I wrote them while waiting for a compile.  As for it being a case of practice, isn't everything.

Comment: `Node const* root` means that `root` is a pointer to a const Node.  `const` always modifies whatever is to the left of it.  If nothing is to the left of it, then other rules apply, but it's generally better to be systematic, and always put it immediately to the right of what it modifies.  (This is particularly important when `typedef` are involved.  `typedef int* Ptr; const Ptr pi;` doesn't mean what it seems.  Using `Ptr const pi;` does.  (Both definitions of `pi` mean exactly the same thing: `int *const pi;`.)

Comment: thanks for clarification on this; I'll put some traversal methods in next :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
        this->left = FibTree(n - 1, this); // This line errors 'Cannot convert 'FibTree' to 'FibTree*' in assignment
        this->right = FibTree(n - 2, this); // This line errors 'Cannot convert 'FibTree' to 'FibTree*' in assignment
```

should be

```
        this->left = new FibTree(n - 1, this);
        this->right = new FibTree(n - 2, this);
```

Not sure why you are passing root to your constructor though, you don't do anything with it.

Comment: The obvious issue (obvious for people with some experience in OO programming) is that he is confounding nodes and trees.  I think your solution might actually work in this case, but only by accident; if you don't keep the difference between the two concepts in mind, you'll run into problems somewhere.